# Quotes in JQL query not working in Jira script console

Tags: jira, quotes, atlassian-sourcetree, jira-rest-api, script-console

I am using a JQL query in my code that I am writing in the script console of Jira and I am having some issues with the quotes in the script console as you can see below.
[image]

Here is the code:

```
    def query3 = ""
    try{
     query3 = jqlQueryParser.parseQuery("project = \""+myproject.getName()+"\" and created >= -365d and issuetype in (""\"Defect"\"", "Code Roll-in - Maintenance", "Code Roll-in - New Version"))

    }catch(Exception e){
        log.warn("MounaException "+e)
    }
```

Anyone knows how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution:

query3 = jqlQueryParser.parseQuery('project = "'+myproject.getName()+ '" and created >= -365d and issuetype in ("Defect","Code Roll-in - Maintenance","Code Roll-in - New Version")')